# C Socket stuck in read when sending from x86 to x64

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm writing a tiny email server / client for class project. When I run the client and server on same machine, everything works fine. When I run the server on a x86 machine and client on x64 machine, I am stuck in read. When I run the server on a x64 machine and client on x86 machine, read is complete, but when I print the string, its blank. Following is the function I use to read

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
int readn(int sd, char *buf, int n) {
    printf("readn via utils. %d, %s, %d\n", sd, buf, n);
    int toberead;
    char * ptr;

    toberead = n;
    ptr = buf;
    while (toberead > 0) {
        int byteread;
        fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %d, byteread: %d\n",toberead, byteread );
        byteread = read(sd, ptr, toberead);
        fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %d, byteread: %d\n",toberead, byteread );

        if (byteread <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "byteread val: %d",byteread);
            if (byteread == -1)
                perror("read");
            raise (6);
            return (0);
        }

        toberead -= byteread;
        ptr += byteread;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Finished readn. %s\n", buf);
    return (1);
}
```

Other utility functions that use or have impact on readn

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

Packet *recvpkt(int sd)
{
    printf("Recvpkt via utils.\n");
    Packet *pkt;

    /* allocate space for the pkt */
    pkt = (Packet *) calloc(1, sizeof(Packet));
    if (!pkt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error : unable to calloc\n");
        return(NULL);
    }

    /* read the message type */
    if (!readn(sd, (char *) &pkt->type, sizeof(pkt->type))) {
        free(pkt);
        return(NULL);
    }

    /* read the message length */
    if (!readn(sd, (char *) &pkt->lent, sizeof(pkt->lent))) {
        free(pkt);
        return(NULL);
    }
    pkt->lent = ntohl(pkt->lent);

    /* allocate space for message text */
    if (pkt->lent > 0) {
        pkt->text = (char *) malloc(pkt->lent);
        if (!pkt) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error : unable to malloc\n");
            return(NULL);
        }

        /* read the message text */
        if (!readn(sd, pkt->text, pkt->lent)) {
            freepkt(pkt);
            return(NULL);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Reading packet complete succesfully.\n");

    /* done reading */
    return(pkt);
}

int sendpkt(int sd, char typ, long len, char *buf)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Send packet via utils.\n");
    char tmp[8];
    long siz;

    /* write type and lent */
    bcopy(&typ, tmp, sizeof(typ));
    siz = htonl(len);
    bcopy((char *) &siz, tmp+sizeof(typ), sizeof(len));
    write(sd, tmp, sizeof(typ) + sizeof(len));

    /* write message text */
    if (len > 0)
        write(sd, buf, len);
    return(1);
}

void freepkt(Packet *pkt)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Freeing packet.\n");
    free(pkt->text);
    free(pkt);
}
```

Output of the above in first case (x86 to x64) is below.

```
readn via utils. 3, , 1
toberead: 1, byteread: 0
toberead: 1, byteread: 1
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 8
toberead: 8, byteread: 1
toberead: 8, byteread: 8
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 57
toberead: 57, byteread: 58
toberead: 57, byteread: 53
toberead: 4, byteread: 53
```

Output of the function from x64 to x86 is below

```
readn via utils. 3, , 1
toberead: 1, byteread: -1079631112
toberead: 1, byteread: 1
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 4
toberead: 4, byteread: 1
toberead: 4, byteread: 4
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 57
toberead: 57, byteread: -1079631112
toberead: 57, byteread: 57
Finished readn. 
Reading packet complete succesfully.
>>
```

Data is supposed to be printed after >>

Let me know if my question is clear or if any other information. I spent 2 full days trying to fix this but in vain.

**Update**: Function that calls readn is updated.

Comment: The first `fprintf(stderr, ...` introduces undefined behaviour as `byteread` is accessed uninitialised. Doing `int byteread = 0;` would fix this **and** make the logging output much more senseful.

Comment: Also `read()` returns `ssize_t` and takes `size_t` not `int` as the code does. This mistake would make the code fail for large chunks of data.

Comment: If the data received does not carry a `0` as last character, this line `fprintf(stderr, "Finished readn. %s\n", buf);` would also introduced undefined behaviour. Change it to print the buffer byte by byte or test for the trailing `0` and add it "by hand" prior to printing the "string".

Answer (score 2):

On x64, you are reading 1 byte then 8 bytes (then some more bytes).
On x86, you are reading 1 byte then 4 bytes (then some more bytes).
This is a clue about the mismatch between the x86 and x64 versions of your program.

Perhaps you are calling `sendn` like this:

```
long l;
l = /* something */;
sendn(sd, &l, sizeof l);
```

`long`s are 32 bits wide on 32-bit Linux, and 64 bits wide on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: You are correct the issues here most likley is an XY-problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem." - the question does not mention any attempted solution. The author is looking for the problem in the wrong place though.

Comment: Posting the code to us asking for help is the attempted solution, where as the OP does not mention how the code is used, which seems to be the actual problem? But perhaps I got the XY-problem-idiom wrong.

Comment: @immibis, thank you. I should have pasted the sendpkt function earlier that would give you more insight on what I'm doing. Now I understand the problem. Send is sending 1 + 4 + 57, Receive is receiving is 1 + 8 + 53, but is waiting to receive 57 where the remaining 4 is not available. Any suggestions on how to fix this ? The idea of typ in send packet is specific to this code, to tell what time of message it is like - Welcome message, Data message, User name etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code:

- The first `printf(""readn via utils ...)` assumes that the memory pointed to by `buf` had been initialised, at least `buf[0]` should have been set to `'\0'`, else the beaviour of this call is undefined.
- The first `fprintf(stderr, ...` introduces undefined behaviour as `byteread` is accessed uninitialised. Doing `int byteread = 0;` would fix this and make the logging output much more senseful.
- Also `read()` returns `ssize_t` and takes `size_t` not `int` as the code does. This mistake would make the code fail for large chunks of data.
- The call to `perror()` might not reflect the error happend in the call to `read()` as the value of `errno` might have been changed by the call to `fprintf()` done prior to `perror()`.
- If the data received does not carry a `'\0'` as last character, so this line `fprintf(stderr, "Finished readn. %s\n", buf);` would also introduced undefined behaviour. Change it to print the buffer byte by byte or test for the trailing `0` and add it "by hand" prior to printing the "string".

Some fixes to the code as per my comments above:

```
int readn(int sd, char * buf, size_t n)
{
  printf("readn via utils. %d, %s, %zu\n", sd, buf, n);
  size_t toberead = n;
  char * ptr = buf;

  while (toberead > 0)
  {
    int errno_save = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %zu\n", toberead);

    ssize_t byteread = read(sd, ptr, toberead);
    errno_save = errno;

    fprintf(stderr, "toberead: %zu, byteread: %zd\n", toberead, byteread);

    if (byteread <= 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "byteread val: %zd\n", byteread);
      if (byteread == -1)
      {
        errno = errno_save;
        perror("read");
      }
      raise(6);
      return (0);
    }

    toberead -= byteread;
    ptr += byteread;
  }

  if ('\0' != buf[n]) /* This assumes buf is one byte **larger** then n. */
  {
    buf[n] = '\0';
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Finished readn. %s\n", buf);
  return (1);
}
```

---

As a final comment: This construction to read data from a socket, either assumes the caller knows in advance how many bytes would be sent, or the connection will be closed after less data had been sent, otherwise (that is less bytes then `n` are sent and the connection is **not** closed) a call to `readn()` would block.

See [*immibis*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20310602/694576) for a reason why the latter the could be an issue to your setup (32bit vs. 64bit).

Comment: After adding these debugs, I still don't get more information. I'm unable to format this output here. Recvpkt via utils.
readn via utils. 3, , 1
toberead: 1
toberead: 1, byteread: 1
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 8
toberead: 8
toberead: 8, byteread: 8
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 57
toberead: 57
toberead: 57, byteread: 53
toberead: 4

Comment: Same function on x86 to x86 printed the following. Recvpkt via utils.
readn via utils. 3, , 1
toberead: 1
toberead: 1, byteread: 1
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 4
toberead: 4
toberead: 4, byteread: 4
Finished readn. 
readn via utils. 3, , 57
toberead: 57
toberead: 57, byteread: 57
Finished readn. Welcome to Santosh's Email Server, running on port 5945.
Reading packet complete succesfully.