# Trouble while reading from socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, io

I am trying to read characters from a socket; here is the function I created for this, largely inspired from [Here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/sockets/read_line.c.html), where I remove some unrelevant parts here (this sample is compiling correctly).

```
int process(int socketfd, void *buffer, int n)
{
  int totread = 0;
  char ch;
  int numread;

  for(;;)
  {
    numread = read(socketfd, &ch, 1);

    if(numread == 0) {
        if (totread == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        if(totread < n-1) {
            totread++;
            printf("totread: %d\n", totread);
            printf("Here is OK, ch value gets printed %c\n", ch);
            *buffer++ = ch;
            printf("With help provided, this line gets printed\n");
            printf("But the value <%s> of buffer, is blank (<> output)\n, buffer);
        }
        if (ch == '\n') {
            printf("%c\n", ch);
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            break;
        }
    }
}
return totread;
}
```

I can't understand why the second line does not get printed.
Obviously, the `*buf++ = ch` instruction is faulty; But it looks like correct. It simply affects the character read to the next value of the array of characters buf. I don't see errors or warnings at compile time, the client disconnects after the first line gets printed, and the second one is not reached.

EDIT

Here is how I initialize my buffer:

```
char *buffer = "";
int l = process(newsockfd, buffer, 100);
printf("Number read (function network) %d\n", l);
```

This is probably not the appropriate way to do it; I have also tried specifying a fixed length such as `char buffer = [255];` The function does not exit then but nothing get printed. I'm quite a newbie in C programming, many thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say the second line does not get printed, I presume you mean because the program crashes. This is likely to be a segv caused by writing to `buf` when `buf` is either `NULL` or invalid memory. What happens when you run it under `gdb`, having compiled with `-g` to include debugging symbols?

Comment: Is buffer big enough? Also, I believe buf[0] is never written to, seems like a potential problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Please also show us **how** you call this function and expecially how the buffer passed in is defined and **initialised**.

Comment: Also: Did you leave out the code for error checking by intention to make this example better readbale?

Comment: What is the  `n` (passed in) for?

Comment: For a working version of your function you might like to have look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20310622/694576 However, in any case make sure the buffer-pointer passed into the function refers to enough valid memory.

Comment: cen, alk, I edited my question accordingly.
alk, the ``n`` is used to read at most n characters, and ignore any further ones (this does not appear on the function)

Comment: "*is used to read at most `n` characters*" but the code shown does **not** respect this maximum of `n`!

Comment: This `char buffer = [255];` isn't valid C. It won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int process(..., void * b, ...
{
  ...

  *b++ = ...
```

Dereferencing and/or incrementing a `void`-pointer is not valid C. The compiler should have at least warned you about this.

Recompile your code with all warnings on (for gcc pass the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for this). Then fix the code until no more warning are issued.

---

Referring your edit on how the function in question is called:

This

```
char *buffer = "";
```

does not declare a buffer, but just a pointer. This pointer points to a string literal of size `1`. String literals a constant by definition.

To summarise: You provide to your `process()`-function a pointer to constant memory of size `1`.

Issues with this:

1. You cannnot read into constant memory.
2. An even if 1. would not apply you could only read in `1` byte.

To fix this change the code as follows:

```
char buffer[100] = ""; /* Define a buffer of 100 characters size and 
                          initialise it to all `0`s. */
int l = process(newsockfd, buffer, 100);
```

---

As per `process()` blocking, you need to look at the `read()` function: If it gets called but the sender does not send anything it simply does not return as long as the connection is still up.

And: Make `process()` handle the value passed in as `n`.

Comment: I am using eclipse as IDE; maybe this is not the best choice for C programming :/

Comment: @philippe: Eclipse works fine for C programming, at least if you properly .. ;-) If using CDT you are using gcc anyways. Eclipse isn't a compiler/linker, but just the IDE.

Comment: I have added in Eclipse ``-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors``; I corrected every errors, the code compile now. Thanks for your advice for compilation options!

Comment: Not yet handled the value passed in as ``n``, but edited my code taking in account your answer. Now, the program does not crash, as it at least reach the next ``printf``; but the ``buffer``value does not get affected.

Comment: OK, I handle the value passed in as n now; furthermore, I handle the newline break; At this time, I know for sure ``buffer`` get instantiated; as it gets printed in when entering ``\n``

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line to 
char *buf = (char *) buffer;
and compile using gcc with -Werror on

Comment: This does not chance anything :/